# Change color Progress indicator with Databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I try all the ways but I can't change the color of progressbar. I tried to change it not only as binding but also in adapter but it doesn't work. Can you please help?

.....

```
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="160dp"
                            android:progress="25"
                            app:indicatorColor="@{session.getChannel() == Channel.MOBILE ? @color/cerulean : @color/teal}"
                            app:indicatorDirectionCircular="counterclockwise"
                            app:indicatorInset="7dp"
                            app:indicatorSize="140dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:trackColor="#DEE3ED"
                            app:trackCornerRadius="5dp"
                            app:trackThickness="9dp" />
```

i get this error in this case
***Cannot find a setter for <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator app:indicatorColor> that accepts parameter type 'android.content.res.ColorStateList'
If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.***

```
val color = R.color.cerulean
             
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color, 
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

And then I tried this code but again failed. ***undefined***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom binding adapter like this

```
@BindingAdapter("app:indicatorColor")
fun setIndicatorColor(progress: CircularProgressIndicator, color: Int) {
    progress.setIndicatorColor(color)
}
```

After that you can use your code in xml

```
app:indicatorColor="@{session.getChannel() == Channel.MOBILE ? @color/cerulean : @color/teal}"
```